# What do I need to do to increase model accuracy in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I am new to ML and I have a custom data set that has court cases. The columns are charges(str), prior cases(int) and bond amount(int). I am using charges and prior cases as features and the bond amount is my label. Charges(str) is transformed to an int using LabelEncoder.fit_transform. I want to be able to predict what the bond amount would be given the charges and the prior cases. I am using MLPClassifier as my model and have used a couple others. I am only getting around 45% percent accuracy. How can I increase it? Do I just need to try different models? Is there a problem with how I am transforming the data? Could it be possible that scikit-learn just doesn't cut it for the amount of data I am dealing with? The data is super clean and I have gotten rid of outlier bond amounts, but accuracy only increases by about 2%. Just to give you an idea of what the data looks like here are the heads for X and y. Trial and error have driven me here.

X.head() gives me:

```
    charges prior_cases
0   2913.02(A)(1)   0
1   2913.02(A)(1)   0
2   2913.02(A)(1)   5
3   2913.02(A)(1)   3
4   2913.02(A)(1)   22
```

y.head() gives me:

```
    bond
0   2500
1   1000
2   1500
3   1000
4   5000
```

After transforming X,
X[:5] gives me:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 5]
 [0 3]
 [0 22]]
```

Here is all the code:

````
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Bring in CSV
final_df = pd.read_csv('merge.csv')

# Drops bonds rows with bonds over $10,000
outlier = final_df[final_df.bond >= 10000].index
final_df.drop(outlier, inplace=True)

# Gets features from CSV
X = final_df[['prior_cases', 'charges']].values
# Gets labels from CSV
y = final_df[['bond']].values

le = LabelEncoder()
# Transform X data
for i in range(len(X[0])):
    X[:, i] = le.fit_transform(X[:, i])
# Transform y data
for i in range(len(y[0])):
    y[:, i] = le.fit_transform(y[:, i])

# Splits the data, 80% for training
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, train_size=0.8)

# Defines model that the data is trained on
model = MLPClassifier(activation='relu', solver='adam', hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), random_state=1, max_iter=500)

# Trains the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Gives what the predicted label should be
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

# Accuracy of the model
acc = accuracy_score(predictions, y_test)

print('actual:----', le.inverse_transform(y_test[100]))
print('predictions:', le.inverse_transform(predictions[100].reshape(-1,1)))
print('accuracy: ', acc)
```
````

Comment: Try playing around with your regularization parameter `alpha` and learning rate `learning_rate_init`. They're currently at their default values in your model. You could also try increasing the number of hidden layers. Also, `test_size` of 0.1 is enough

Comment: Did you mean to transform `prior_cases` to a label?

Comment: No, prior_cases is going to be one of the features. The label is bond. The bond is what I want to predict given the charge and the prior_cases.

Comment: @mojbius thank you, I will play around with that now. I was originally trying to keep the parameters as default as possible so I could just get a baseline accuracy score